# function expression with namespace

Tags: javascript, json

Actually I am trying to have a namspace [to avoid global variables] without object creation and trying to do the below. But, the execution of the methods data.sum and data.calc.mult with alerts is not getting called. Instead the empty declarations inside data are called. Can I anyone help me know why this is happening?

```
var data = {
    name: "",
    sum: function() {},
    calc : {
        mult: function() {}
    }                       
};

data.sum();
data.calc.mult();

data.sum = function () {
    alert('sum');
};

data.calc.mult = function () {
    alert('mult');
};
```

Comment: You are defining `sum` and `calc.mult` as empty functions, call them (Still empty) and then redefine them. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to the difference between function declarations and assignment of function expressions. ;-)

Comment: RobG can you please help out in uunderstanding this difference between function declarations and assignment of function expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your data.sum() after data.sum function redefinition, you will get the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Define it like this (function definition within object definition):

```
var data = {

    sum: function () {
        alert('sum');
    },
    mult: function () {
        alert('mult');
    }
};

data.sum();
data.mult();
```

Comment: Guys which is best to use function declaration or function expression? Please advise